# multiple lambda function usage

Tags: python, lambda

I am highly struggling with usage of multiple lambda functions.I am giving the complete code but I have problem with last 4 lines.  In the line: `mapped_kernel = lambda X1, X2: kernel(X1, X2, params)`, how is the kernel function called when we do not have the values of X1 and X2? Also in which sequence the below lines are executed.

```
 mapped_kernel = lambda X1, X2: kernel(X1, X2, params)
 mapped_kernel_matrix = lambda X1, X2: qml.kernels.kernel_matrix(X1, X2, mapped_kernel)
 svm_untrained_kernel = SVC(kernel= mapped_kernel_matrix).fit(X_train_dist_zero_not_zero, Y_train_dist_zero_not_zero)
```

I am completely new to python. A little guidance or some link on this can help me up a lot.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_train_dist_zero_not_zero= np.array([[0.5, 0.25],
 [0.28571429, 0.53571429],
 [0.60714286, 0.32142857],
 [0.67857143, 0.53571429],
 [0.42857143, 0.32142857],
 [0.5, 0.5],
 [0.64285714, 0.42857143],
 [0.71428571, 0.39285714],
 [0.78571429, 0.60714286],
 [0.32142857, 0.5]])

Y_train_dist_zero_not_zero= np.array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
## device and circuit characteristics
width = 4
depth = 32 

dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=width)
wires = list(range(width))

# Our Ansatz
def layer(x, params, wires, i0=0, inc=1):
    """Building block of the embedding Ansatz"""
    i = i0
    for j, wire in enumerate(wires):
        qml.Hadamard(wires=[wire])
        qml.RZ(x[i % len(x)], wires=[wire])
        i += inc
        qml.RY(params[0, j], wires=[wire])
        
    qml.broadcast(unitary=qml.CRZ, pattern="ring", wires=wires, parameters=params[1])


@qml.template
def ansatz(x, params, wires):
    """The embedding Ansatz"""
    for j, layer_params in enumerate(params):
        layer(x, layer_params, wires, i0=j * len(wires))
 
def random_params(num_wires, num_layers):
    return np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, (num_layers, 2, num_wires))       
        

# init the embedding kernel
@qml.qnode(dev)
def kernel(x1, x2, params):
    ansatz(x1, params, wires)
    qml.adjoint(ansatz)(x2, params, wires)
    return qml.expval(qml.Projector([0]*width, wires=wires))



# Evaluate the performance with random parameters for the kernel
## Choose random params for the kernel
for i in range(3):
    params = random_params(width, depth)
    
    # fit the SVM on training data   # NEED HELP in understanding below lines
    mapped_kernel = lambda X1, X2: kernel(X1, X2, params)
    mapped_kernel_matrix = lambda X1, X2: qml.kernels.kernel_matrix(X1, X2, mapped_kernel)
    svm_untrained_kernel = SVC(kernel= mapped_kernel_matrix).fit(X_train_dist_zero_not_zero, Y_train_dist_zero_not_zero)

print("Evaluation of performance with Random Parameters complete")
```

I have this code from the link: https://github.com/thubregtsen/qhack/blob/master/paper/noiseless_MNIST.py

Comment: `lambda` is another name for an anonymous function. It would look the same if you did `def mapped_kernel(X1, X2):...`. I'd look into lambdas versus traditional functions, when you would use either, and try experimenting with small programs that use lambda in a simpler context than here

Comment: Thank you @C.Nivs for the response. I will look for some small programs to understand their operation.

Comment: Python standard style actually discourages assigning a lambda to a variable. If you’re going to give the lambda a name, you should just use `def mapped_kernel` which is easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

- if you're going to name lambdas, just use `def` instead; it's much clearer.
- functions that are passed without parentheses are not called when they are passed, they are passed as values and can be called at later time by the callee.

> how is the kernel function called when we do not have the values of X1 and X2?

You don't need the values of `X1` and `X2` when these functions are defined:

```
mapped_kernel = lambda X1, X2: kernel(X1, X2, params)
mapped_kernel_matrix = lambda X1, X2: qml.kernels.kernel_matrix(X1, X2, mapped_kernel)
```

Nothing is calling these functions here. The above is equivalent to this:

```
def mapped_kernel(X1, X2): 
    kernel(X1, X2, params)

def mapped_kernel_matrix(X1, X2): 
    qml.kernels.kernel_matrix(X1, X2, mapped_kernel)
```

Note that `mapped_kernel`, when called, requires that `kernel` and `params` are defined and in scope. Similarly, `mapped_kernel_matrix` requires that `qml.kernels.kernel_matrix` and `mapped_kernel` are defined and in scope.

Note that generally, it's not recommended to assign lambda functions to a name. The whole point of lambdas is that they are unnamed functions. As [PEP8 states](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/):

> The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression)"

The functions will be called when your `SVC` needs them:

```
svm_untrained_kernel = SVC(kernel=mapped_kernel_matrix).fit(X_train_dist_zero_not_zero, Y_train_dist_zero_not_zero)
```

Here you pass `mapped_kernel_matrix` to the `SVC` constructor. It's not called yet, since there's no parentheses `()` behind the name. The function is passed, not called. However, your `SVC` may call `kernel`, which means it's actually calling `mapped_kernel_matrix` and that will work as long as `mapped_kernel` is in scope at that point as well. The [documentation for `SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) states:

> If a callable is given it is used to pre-compute the kernel matrix from data matrices;

And I have to assume that callable is expected to access two parameters, your `X1` and `X2`. (By the way, you should usually name variables and parameters without use capital letters, unless you're naming a class)

Similarly, because `mapped_kernel_matrix` passes `mapped_kernel` to `qml.kernels.kernel_matrix`, the expectation would be that `kernel_matrix` expects a callback in that position and will call `mapped_kernel` as needed. That will work if `params` is in scope at that time.

Note that you could have done this with lambdas:

```
vvm_untrained_kernel = SVC(
    kernel=lambda x1, x2: qml.kernels.kernel_matrix(
        x1, x2, lambda x1, x2: kernel(x1, x2, params)
    )
).fit(X_train_dist_zero_not_zero, Y_train_dist_zero_not_zero)
```

This would wrap everything up in a single command, without naming the lambdas. However, I suspect that your call to `kernel()` is probably related to another error or misunderstanding, or at a minimum poor naming, so you may have to resolve more issues with your code to get something that works. I merely rewrote your code to eliminate the assignments.